# WPF DataGrid changing the cell background color for unused areas

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am heavily customizing the visual appearance of a WPF DataGrid using code behind.  The user can configure the background.  I have no issue setting the cell background for the cells in a data column to a different color.  However I need to also change the cell background color for the undefined area at the end of each row.

For example, I have a row with 6 columns of data.  There is more width to the row than what all of the columns take up, leaving an unused area on the right of the row.  I cannot seem to be able to programmatically in code behind change the background color of this unused area.  I want to set it to be the same as what I used in the rest of the grid.

Anyone have any ideas?  Please only provie code behind solutions, not XAML solutions.

Comment: Would you be able to post a code example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RowBackgroundAlternationIndex2Brush}" />

Comment: "Please only provie code behind solutions, not XAML solutions." << Huh?  If someone provides a XAML solution, just set the properties in code behind.  What a strange requirement.

Comment: The reason I asked for that requirement is that I have seen various XAML solutions that didn't convert well to code behind.  The could be in part my inexperience with WPF and therefore my inability to translate between XAML and code behind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are doing this for a selected item try this:

```
var row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataGrid1.SelectedItem);

row.Background = Brushes.<chosen color>;
```

Other than that you should just be able to set the RowBackground color.

```
dataGrid1.RowBackground = Brushes.<chosen color>;
```

Comment: Thank you.  Initially this did not work, however, I was used a customized data grid template.  When I tried this using the standard template it worked.  Now I just have to see why my template isn't respecting it.

Comment: In your control template you need to ensure that you have a Setter for the RowBackground. You would need this to read RowBackground="{TemplateBinding RowBackground}".

Comment: This link has detailed help to get the DataGridRow and DataGrid Cell in WPF http://techiethings.blogspot.in/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html